# Java Iterator - infinite loop

Tags: java, iterator

What am I doing wrong? Why does this iterator keep running?

```java
default List<T> greedyAlgorithm() {
    List<T> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    T element = selection().next();
        
    while(selection().hasNext()) {
        if(feasibility(lst ,element)) {
            assign(lst, element);
        } else {
            element = selection().next();
        }

        if(solution(lst)){
            return lst;
        }
    }   

    return null;
}
```

The feasibility function checks if the element is viable, if yes assign the element to the list. Then the solution checks if this is the 'algo' solution and returns the list, else check the next element in the list.

Comment: What does the method `selection()` do and return? Does it return an `Iterator`? You should probably call it once and save the `Iterator` in variable and work with that, instead of calling it multiple times. If it returns a new `Iterator` each time you call it, your loop is going to be infinite.

Comment: Yes selection returns an Iterator, Thanks, trying your idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`next` should always be executed inside the loop.

If the `feasibility` condition isn't `false` or `solution` true, then it'll keep running without advancing.

I suggest rearranging the loop so you unconditionally call `next`.

There may also be a problem if `selection` returns a new `Iterator` every call.

Perhaps something like this:

```
default List<T> greedyAlgorithm() {
    List<T> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (
        Iterator<T> selection = selection();
        selection.hasNext();
    ) {
        T element = selection.next();
        if (feasibility(lst ,element)) {
            assign(lst, element);
            if (solution(lst)) {
                return lst;
            }
        }
    }   
    return null;
}
```

If `selection()` returned an `Iterable` you could use a posh for loop. Generally returning a type such as `Iterable` that (kind of) doesn't change internal state is better than a type that does, such as `Iterator` (although there is `remove` so `Iterable.iterator` isn't entirely innocent).